# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatGingerbread

Tags: android

Up until now I was using an android support library support-v4-18.0.2.jar. For some reason I was forced to switch to support-v4-19.0.1.jar. Upon executing my application I got this exception:

> 12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatGingerbread
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$GBViewCompatImpl.getOverScrollMode(ViewCompat.java:406)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(ViewCompat.java:628)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2174)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1917)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1530)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1266)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
>   12-15 10:16:47.382: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This happens when I try all of the activities with a ViewPager in them. Before switch to 19.0.1 this worked fine. As far as I could get from LogCat a class is not defined in support library. I guess it was in the past. The funny thing is that ViewPager in itself is in support library calls it. 
Is this a quirk in support library? Am I missing something? What could be done about that?

EDIT:
I compile for Android 4.4. This is also required by the same change that pushed me to newer support library.
I also tried cleaning.

Comment: What build tool are you using? Did you clean the project after updating the library?

Comment: @Egor Thank you for interest. I have put additional info to original post. Yes. I dod try clean and I build for 4.4. Cannot build for less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issues with SDK build tools. Don't know about the details but update of SDK build tools solved it. I missed the update because two of them followed in short order.